# Unlink Remote Debugging Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I want to unlink remote debugging machine in VS 2012 for Windows Store App. I am unable to find way to do so. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the remote device for C# and Visual Basic projects

- Select the project name in Solution Explorer and then choose **Properties** from the shortcut menu by right clicking on it.
- Select **Debug**.
- Choose other option except **Remote Machine** from the **Target Device** list.
- Remove the network name of the remote device in the **Remote Machine** text box.

Removing the remote device for JavaScript and C++ projects

- Select the project name in Solution Explorer and then choose **Properties** from the shortcut menu by right clicking on it.
- Expand the **Configuration Properties** node and then select **Debugging**.
- Choose other option except **Remote Debugger** from the **Debugger to launch** list.
- Remove the network name of the remote device in the **Machine Name** text box.